# Disabling transient-mark-mode

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, dot-emacs

In my `.emacs` file, I have

```
(setq transient-mark-mode nil)
```

and yet `transient-mark-mode` is activated when I start up Emacs.  Calling `transient-mark-mode` gives the message "transient-mark-mode disabled", but <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> still starts highlighting a region.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have `cua-mode` enabled as well which has similar region highlighting to `transient-mark-mode`. To test this just `M-x cua-mode` (to toggle it on/off) and see if it disables the highlighting.

From `C-h f cua-mode` help:

> CUA mode manages Transient Mark mode internally.  Trying to disable
>   Transient Mark mode while CUA mode is enabled does not work; if you
>   only want to highlight the region when it is selected using a
>   shifted movement key, set `cua-highlight-region-shift-only'.